# Perl DBI Sample with MySQL DDL

Tags: mysql, perl

I've been experimenting with Perl and MySql and wrote this code for connecting and writing to a database:

```
#   MySQL DDL to create database used by code 
#
#   CREATE DATABASE sampledb;
#
#   USE sampledb;
#   
#   CREATE TABLE `dbtable` (
#     `id`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
#     `demo` longtext,
#     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
#   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

# PERL MODULES
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI; #http://dbi.perl.org

# CONFIG VARIABLES
my $platform = "mysql";
my $database = "sampledb";
my $host = "localhost";
my $port = "3306";
my $username = "root";
my $password = "password";

# DATA SOURCE NAME
my $dsn = "dbi:$platform:$database:$host:$port";

# PERL DBI CONNECT
my $connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password);

# VARS for Examples
my $query;
my $query_handle;
my $id;
my $demo;

# Example 1 using prepare() and execute() INSERT

    # SAMPLE VARIABLE AND VALUES TO PASS INTO SQL STATEMENT
    $id = 1;
    $demo = "test";

    # INSERT
    $query = "INSERT INTO dbtable (id, demo) VALUES ('$id', '$demo')";
    $query_handle = $connect->prepare($query);
    $query_handle->execute();
    undef $query;

# Example 2 using do() UPDATE   

    # SAMPLE VARIABLE AND VALUES TO PASS INTO SQL STATEMENT
    $id = 1;
    $demo = "test 2";

    # UPDATE
    $query = "UPDATE dbtable SET demo = '$demo' WHERE id = $id";
    $query_handle = $connect->do($query);
    undef $query;
```

Is this the correct/idiomatic way to access a database in Perl? Are there any other improvements I could make?

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Would you describe what exactly your code does? I see a DDL and some insert and update statements. It's all right to ask for a general review, but we need more context.

Comment: @Michael K: It's Perl for a database connector and sample INSERT and UPDATE, and very common code. Do you know Perl? Is there a template for information expected? Thanks!

Comment: @Olli: Yes, it's working code -- and I wanted feedback; question is closed, and not posting again without and understanding of WHY it was closed. Thought that was the point of CodeReview. May I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @blunders: With your comments in mind I've edited the post to add that context in. The confusion arises because we aren't certain why the code was written. If it was meant as a module in a larger program we would read it differently than what it appears it is, a proof-of-concept database access standalone. Please look at my edits and edit the post as necessary - they should at least give you a guide to the information that would be helpful. I'm reopening the post now that there's more information available.

Comment: @Michael K: Thanks for the edits, I've reviewed them and you're correct, they do give a better content to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things I noticed:

When you connect to the database, you don't check that the connection succeeded. The most common way I've seen to do this in Perl is:

```
my $connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password)
   or die "Connection Error:  DBI::errstr\n";
```

If the connection fails, the program will then display the connection failure message so you can see what's going on.

I see that you use two different ways of accessing the database. It would be better to pick one and use it for all your inserts/updates unless there is a compelling reason not to - it keeps future readers from trying to figure out why you did it differently. In this case I'd reccomend using `execute` since it allows you to execute multiple times:

```
$query_handle = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO dbtable (id, demo) VALUES (?, ?)");
$query_handle->execute($id, $demo);
$id = 2;
$demo = "test2";
$query_handle->execute($id, $demo);
```

Also don't forget to disconnect:

```
$connect->disconnect;
```

Comment: +1 @Michael K: If I'm reading your answer correctly, you're saying "do()" does not allow for placeholders, but execute() does, right, or no? Main reason I've heard to use placeholders is to prevent SQL injection; which in this case would not be an issue, since the code is only used as an utility for importing data from flat files to a database. Agree about everything else, thanks!!

Comment: @blunders: I'm sorry, I made a mistake there. `do` is for executing a query only once and *does* allow placeholders. The advantage of `prepare`/`execute` is that it creates a procedure on the database that you can execute multiple times with many arguments. So you could prepare the statement and then loop over the file, calling `execute` for every data set. It's faster than creating a new query every time, like `do`.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that.